# How to make rowIndex as sequentially increasing number across all page numbers in gridview paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with pagination and each page contains 10 rows. When navigating to second page(`OnPageIndexChanging`) I want to consider rowIndex as sequentially increasing number across all page numbers.

For example, if the rowindex ends at 9 on page 1 then the rowindex should start with 10 for the first row in the next page of the `GridView`.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is:

Create a `ViewState` and count indexes on every page and put the last index in `ViewState`.